# How can a modal reopen another modal? (Angular 4+)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a *modalA* (form) that opens on a click on main page. 
The *modalA* has button that needs to open another *modalB* (form).

When I cancel the *modalB*, I don't want it to go back to main page, I would like to return to *modalA*. How can I do this?

**modalA**

```
public openModal(): void {
    const record = { email: this.email, name: this.name, familyName: this.familyName };
    this.modal.closeModal();
    this.DeleteModalComponent.showModal(record);
 }
```

```
<div class="logo">
     <button class="user-modal-form" md-button (click)="openModal()" aria-label="remove">
         <span>Delete user</span>
     </button>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you using as a ui component? angular material or ngx-bootstrap etc??

Comment: If you're using angular material you'll need 2 separate components as modals, which will have 2 different ref's you can use to call ```this.modal.closeModal()```

Comment: I do have 2 separate components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used EventEmitter in ModalB component and it worked.

```
  @Output() onHide: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onClose: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-bootstrap . Check out this u can get a help
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/modal-stacked.ts